# Expo App with Google Login is not redirecting to app

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I having a problem with my Google Sign In, I'm Currently using EXPO app ***I wish at all cost not to eject / opt out of Expo***, the problem is that when I click on the Button to log in with Google in my App it does take me to the login page for me inside the browser, but once I put my Google credentials, it just lands inside the Google.com page.

I checked a lot of posts but still I'm unable to get it to come back to the app.

My app Code to log in is:

```
//import de Google en Expo
import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';
import * as AppAuth from 'expo-app-auth';

export const googleLogin = () => {
    console.log('***Entro en Google***');
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const result = await Google.logInAsync({
              androidClientId: '***my ID Censored***',
              scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
              behavior: 'web',
              redirectUrl: `${AppAuth.OAuthRedirect}:/oauthredirect`
            });
            console.log('***Hizo Consulta***');
            if (result.type === 'success') {
              console.log(result.accessToken);
            } else {
              return { cancelled: true };
            }
          } catch (e) {
            return { error: true };
          }
    }
};
```

I checked on many posts that the issue was the redirect URL and I tried setting 4 options:

1. `${AppAuth.OAuthRedirect}:/oauthredirect`
2. `${AppAuth.OAuthRedirect}:/oauthredirect/google`
3. 'host.exp.exponent:/oauth2redirect/google'
4. 'host.exp.exponent:/oauth2redirect/'

None of them worked, I did the last 2 of host.exp.exponent as that is the Bundle Identifier used by Expo on their documentation:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/

**Create an Android OAuth Client ID**

1. Select "Android Application" as the Application Type. Give it a name
   if you want (maybe "Android Development").
2. Run openssl rand -base64
   32 | openssl sha1 -c in your terminal, it will output a string that
   looks like A1:B2:C3 but longer. Copy the output to your clipboard.
   Paste the output from the previous step into the
   "Signing-certificate fingerprint" text field.
3. Use host.exp.exponent as the "Package name".
   4.Click "Create"
4. You will now see a modal with the Client ID.
5. The client ID is used in the androidClientId option for Google.loginAsync (see code example below).

I did just that, and now it always gets stuck in the google.com page, any Ideas or recommendations?

Kind Regards

Comment: No solution yet found

Comment: Any solution found ????

Comment: Nop amd I doubt it will be one

Answer (score 0):

What have you added to your bundle id (e.g "Apple bundle ID")?

Take into account that there is a difference between production and development.

In development, you should use the default expo apple bundle id so you will be allowed to use the google login (and you won't get redirect_fail).

The default apple bundle id for development using expo is: `host.exp.exponent`

In production, you should have your own bundle id.

Please write up a follow-up message if any extra help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

'expo-google-app-auth' is deprecated:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-google-app-auth

Author message:

Please migrate to expo-auth-session
```

You need use expo-auth-session.

Example of code:

```
//imports

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

//component name 

const [requestGoogle, responseGoogle, promptAsyncGoogle] =
    Google.useAuthRequest({
      expoClientId: "clientId",
      androidClientId: "clientId,
      webClientId: "clientId",
      iosClientId: "clientId",
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (responseGoogle?.type === "success") {
      const token = responseGoogle.params.access_token;
       
      // some code to get google data by google token 

    }
  }, [responseGoogle]);

// in your button add to onPress={promptAsyncGoogle}
```

P.S: it works with libs:

```
"expo": "~47.0.13"
"expo-auth-session": "~3.8.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a solution in 2023 all I did to get this to work was changing my package name on Google Cloud. Like Balanagu said here. Change your package name in google cloud, change all letters to small caps, and change it in your project as well. This worked for me, didn't have to do anything else. Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In app.json,
package name as to be all in small letters like com.app.cloneapp

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand the solution should I add this or?

Comment: hey @ReneAlas, just change the package name to small letters from capital letter(if you haven't keep) in app.json file

Comment: Hey @Balangu Tashwangth thanks  for the response I tried but as I'm in expo the name is not in reverso domain notation, just says: "name": "alianza". I tried doing the notation like com.alianza.app and still getting the same error, I can log in, but it doesn't come back to the app.

Comment: @ReneAlas  check it once running in the developer mode, working or not google sign in ????

Comment: The app itself works in developer mode for everything but Google Sign In, and the issue itself is just coming back to the app after signing in, in Google.

Comment: @ReneAlas, In developer mode it won't come back check the code, only production mode it will do..., once check it is happening developer mode or production mode

Comment: It is working fine in Release apk but i want to check in debug mode, because there is some error coming and i want to check it.